Save File to SharePoint with document type set
I would like to save an excel file (using the macro’s) to SharePoint and put it on the right location.
I search a lot on the internet but could not find the solution where I’m looking for.
1)    Step 1: Save the document on sharepoint (this works):
Dim all variables

SPExcelFile = SPlocation & "/" & Year(Date) & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Split(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & ".xlsm"
SPPdfFile = SPlocation & "/" & Year(Date) & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Day(Date) & "_" & Split(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")(0) & ".pdf"
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SPExcelFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=SPPdfFile

2)    Step 2: Save the document and set the properties.
This is where I’m looking for, I guess I just have to add some code to Step 1 to add the properties.
But at this moment I need to manually change next properties content type & maintenance document type.
Does anyone now how to do this in the macro, so this can be automated ?

Which properties would you like to set? For example, title, tags, categories etc.

Hi, i'm not a sharepoint expert. I think we have some custom fields. But when i try to save an Excel file in Sharepoint, i get a popup that asks me the next info: title "Choose Content Type". Text: "The Web server requires you to pick the type of document before it can be saved. Select a type below." Then there is a subtitle "Content Type" where i have a combobox with the options: 1. "Document" and 2. "Maintenance Document". I would like to set it to maintenance document.

Then the second option i want to set is: When the file is saved as maintenance document, it declared as "Maintenance document - unassigned" we got diffrent maintenance types, when i select the item i get a sidebar with multiple fields: Access field, properties field. In the properties field, here the content type has set "maintenance document", but i also want to set the "maintenance document type" to the choise 'preventive' + the "document status" to "approved" -> i guess this are custom fields. Thanks in advance

I'm unfamiliar with those properties, if possible, could you attach link to a screenshot for the menus? Also this resource might be useful for querying built-in and custom document properties.
Built-in Properties
Custom Properties
